# test script fails when triggered using jenkins gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver error message

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ojdbc, cucumber-java

I have added a ojdbc14 jar file to gradle project in Intellij, my test scripts including db validations runs fine when triggered the test cases using the run option in Intellij. But the same test script fails when triggered through the CI using jenkins and gives me the below error

```
Feature: 3D secure code scenarios
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at util.OracleDBService.createDriver(OracleDBService.java:88)
    at util.OracleDBService.openConnection(OracleDBService.java:56)
    at util.OracleDBService.executeQuery(OracleDBService.java:13)
    at pages.DBListOfQuery.getOrderStatusFromDB(DBListOfQuery.java:67)
    at steps.FlowScenarioSteps.verify_the_order_placed_for_order_id_and_validate_order_xml(FlowScenarioSteps.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
```

My project.iml file includes jdbc library

```
 <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Downloads/ojdbc14.jar/ojdbc14.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Jenkins` doesn't know nothing about `ojdbc14.jar`. When `Jenkins` fires job in this example want to compile project, tests some classes and so on, it must know about provided libraries.

I have no idea how `Jenkins` is configured in your company or on your local computer but you need to add manually this `ojdbc14.jar` to its local repository. Local repository can for example be handled by `maven` or `gradle`.

So in this case you need to configure `Jenkins` to use `gradle` and add `ojdbc14.jar` to `gradle` local repository.